# custom 404 page for nonexistent php files

Tags: apache, error-handling, errordocument

I just tried to redirect nonexistent files on the server to my custom 404 page but it only redirects *.html* files.

I used that in my .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404/404.html
```

How can I redirect all nonexistent files (including *.php*) to my custom page?

Thanks

Comment: Wait, we _are_ talking about Apache, right...?

Comment: Do you use some other mechanisms like mod_rewrite that can get in conflict with this?

Answer (score 0):

This should redirect all nonexistent files *in the same directory* as that `.htaccess` file. What happens in case a nonexistent PHP file is requested?

Comment: actually depends on browser, in firefow i get "no input file specified." in chrome just "HTTP 404 - File not found"

Answer (score 0):

It could be that some other rule or directive (for example, a redirect) processes the PHP files before it gets to your `ErrorDocument` directive. Without more information, this is impossible to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteuRule .* home.html [L]
```

If you wants 404 redirection `RewriteuRule .* home.html [R=404,L]`